# how do you graph xyz=1

Tags: multivariable-calculus

is there a graphic device that can graph xyz=1?
if so, what does it look like?
i tried the 'geogebra 3d calculator' and it didn't work out so well

edit* thank you so much for answering! it helped me a lot

Comment: Just try $z=\frac1{xy}$. It's easier to visualize that way too.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to **use Google**. Type 1/(x*y) in google, you will get a 3-d plot.

Another free tool is [3-D Plot](http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/graph3d/) and [Math-Picks](http://grapher.mathpix.com/).

There are other more fancy tools such as MatLab, but they are not free.